# How to use insertBefore on a element inside a iframe by a data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a iframe inside my page and i want to move a element by select the destination with a "data-attribute", so i trie to do this:

```
var ifr=frames['myiframeID'].document;
var element='#idofdiv';
var destination='value_for_my_attribute';
```

I trie it in this way

```
$(element,ifr).insertBefore('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]');
```

and in this way

```
$(element,ifr).insertBefore('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifr);
```

Both way failes, nothing happens.

What i do wrong?

Update
I check this:

```
console.log('check',$(element,ifr), $('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifra));
```

Both will return the object.

Comment: Are you satisfying the *Same-origin policy* rules?

Comment: yes, all other operations work - only at this part i cannot find a way,i think i do the part of the last selector in a wrong way?"('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifr)"

Comment: Have you tried manually selecting the element with the data attribute, so that you also assure that it's looking for an element within the desired IFRAME? I would try replacing the string data selector with `$('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifr)`. The thing is that your insertBefore selector may not match any elements.

Comment: I've update my post, at the end you can see the result of manually selecting - that will work. Now i have to figure out, why my code to insertBefore wont work!?

Comment: A assume if you change you code to `$(element,ifr).insertBefore($('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifr));` it starts working?

Comment: :-)) Great, it seems that this works!

Comment: sure, and thanks a lot,and please upvote my question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: As you say you do satisfy the *Same origin policy* so in theory you should be able to access and manipulate subordinate IFRAME DOM.

The reason why it won't work is the way selectors work. If both elements are supposed to be within a different frame than where the code is running, then they both need to be selected providing their parent frame. Your code doesn't. Only the element being inserted is correctly selected, but the selector of the target data attributed reference element isn't.

```
$(element, ifr).insertBefore('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]');
// ^ correct                 ^ incorrect
```

As per jQuery documentation, you can't simply add parent element to the `insertBefore` function call.

This should therefore work:

```
var el = $(element, ifr);
var ref = $('[data-my-attribute="'+destination+'"]', ifr);
el.insertBefore(ref);
// or
ref.before(el);
```

This should work as expected.